# How execute cleartool command in Rational ClearCase?

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

I would like to run a command in `cleartool`.

I am, however, unable to understand how do I launch this `cleartool` from Rational Clearcase.

Is it a plugin for ClearCase?
(I am using Clearcase explorer on Windows 7)

Answer (score 0):

It is a command line interface (see [IBM man page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/c_hood_cleartool_cli.htm), and "[Working at the command line](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.tutorial.doc/a_cli_singleline.htm)").
It supposes that your `$PATH` (or `%PATH%` on Windows) environment variable references the `<ClearCase installation directory>/bin`.

Open a shell (like a DOS windows in windows, or ksh/bash/zsh on Unix/Linux) and type:

```
cleartool
```

That will open a sub-shell in which you can type cleartool command like `lsvob`.

I prefer, however, typing cleartool in the native shell:

```
cleartool --ver
cleartool lsvob
...
```

(instead of typing those commands within a cleartool session)
That allows for a better error trapping and recovering process, directly handled in the native shell.

---

Note: above is for ClearCase 7.x.
For CCRC, or ClearCase 8.x (which is using ClearTeam Explorer, a modern version of CCRC), you would be [using `rcleartool`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=0&uid=swg24021929).

Answer (score -1):

Even I am using clearcase explorer on Windows 7.

Access the machine using a ssh client like putty and run cleartool it should take you into that command line interface. if not, you need to set cleartool in path.

Let me know what more you need.